# WordPress nav_menu_link_attributes Not Working

Tags: menus, filters

I am attempting to add a data attribute to all menu items, but it's simply not working. I am using `wp_nav_menu` to call my menu walker as well.

```
function menu_anchor_attributes ( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['data-menuanchor'] = $item->attr_title;
return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_anchor_attributes', 10, 3 );
```

I am using JointsWP as my framework, which includes this walker:

```
// The Top Menu
function joints_top_nav() {
     wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container' => false,                           // Remove nav container
        'menu_class' => 'horizontal menu',       // Adding custom nav class
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">%3$s</ul>',
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // Where it's located in the theme
        'depth' => 5,                                   // Limit the depth of the nav
        'fallback_cb' => false,                         // Fallback function (see below)
        'walker' => new Topbar_Menu_Walker()
    ));
} 

// Big thanks to Brett Mason (https://github.com/brettsmason) for the awesome walker
class Topbar_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question ( using the `edit` link above ) and add in your Walker Class please? It could be that it doesn't call the filter.

Comment: Of course, I have included the walker.

Comment: What happens if you put `( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) ? $item->attr_title : 'test';` in your attributes filter? I have a suspicion that `attr_title` is an empty string and the attribute is being ignored because of this.

Comment: Nothing happens, unfortunately. Not even an empty data-menuanchor attribute displays.

Comment: Something else is the issue then, if I paste the provided code above into my theme and add the conditional in the comment above - it adds the attribute to the anchor tag as expected. Try removing this functionality from your theme and add it to a WordPress default theme like Twenty Fifteen or something of the sort. If you're able to get it working - from there you'll need to disable all the installed plugins and tear your theme apart until you figure out what is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: I just tried putting it in the Twentysixteen theme and it did not work for me.

Comment: My apologies, I just tested your solution again and it worked this time - adding the empty condition returned "test". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an attribute is empty WordPress filters decide just not to show the attribute so a simple test for this is the following:

```
function menu_anchor_attributes ( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['data-menuanchor'] = ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) ? $item->attr_title : 'test';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_anchor_attributes', 10, 3 );
```

This way, if a title attribute hasn't been filled into the back-end it will still display the attribute with a value of `test`.

Answer (score 0):

The fiter `nav_menu_link_attributes` only works on menus that are created in wp-admin. By default `wp_nav_menu` returns the published pages even if you did not create a menu on the backend but as soon as you click "create menu" on Appearance -> Menus the filter does its job